# How to add bPopup to html site?

Tags: jquery

I'm young in this, I need help. I have site, and I want to add simple popup with blocking content and X button. I google and found bPopup, but I don't know how to add it to my simple index.php file? Who can help..? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
```

http://fancybox.net/ is your friend. Add a `div` to your HTML, and create with jQuery this code, so it will create a window as you like to have. You need to put the code between `<script></script>` and also load jQuery into your page.